# TemplateDoesNotExist at /test2/ the app is in python and django

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

`name.html` cannot be found

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import Get_name


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Get_name(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/THANKS/')
    else:
        form = Get_name()
    return render(request,'name.html',{'from':form})
```

`name.html:`why python is not able to find my template? my template dir structure is `test2/templates/test2/name.html`

```
 <form action="/username/" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class Get_name(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(label='username',max_length='50')
```

**test2/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views


urlpatterns=[
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    ]
```

**test1/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url , include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test2/',include('test2.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Where is the template?

Comment: append `test2` before template name while rendering `render(request, 'test2/name.html',{'from':form})`

Comment: please edit your question so it's easier to read and be used again by others.

Comment: after changing to test2/name.html it is working but the form is not generated

Comment: @chaitanya You have a typo `{'from':form}` 'from' instead of 'form'.

Comment: thank you  @guillermochamorro

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve the problem.

## Modify your views such that.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Get_name(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/THANKS/')
    else:
        form = Get_name()
    return render(request,'test2/name.html',{'from':form})
```

prepend template name with `test2` such that `return render(request,'test2/name.html',{'from':form})`